# NSInternalInconsistencyException with NSUserDefaults when using method setValue: forPath

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults, setvalue

My code is as follows:

```
NSMutableDictionary *configure = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"configure"];
if (!configure){    
configure = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[configure setValue:[NSMutableDictionary dictionary] forKeyPath:@"select"] ;

[configure setValue:[NSMutableDictionary dictionary] forKeyPath:@"select.around"];
[configure setValue: @"All" forKeyPath:@"select.around.name"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:configure forKey:@"configure"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
NSString *keyPath = @"configure.select.around";
NSMutableDictionary *aroundConfigure = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKeyPath:keyPath] mutableCopy];
[aroundConfigure setObject:@"" forKey:@"name"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:aroundConfigure forKeyPath:keyPath];
```

It's crashing every time with the error below:

```
** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00daebe9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00f035c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00d67628 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00d6759a +[NSException raise:format:] + 58
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00dad401 -[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:] + 209
    5   Foundation                          0x0004b34d -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 399
    6   Foundation                          0x0004b34d -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 399
    7   Untitled                            0x00002429 -[UntitledAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 774
    8   UIKit                               0x002b81fa -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1163
    9   UIKit                               0x002ba55e -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 439
    10  UIKit                               0x002c4db2 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1533
    11  UIKit                               0x002bd202 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 71
    12  UIKit                               0x002c2732 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
    13  GraphicsServices                    0x016e4a36 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00d90064 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00cf06f7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00ced983 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00ced240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00ced161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    19  UIKit                               0x002b9fa8 -[UIApplication _run] + 636
    20  UIKit                               0x002c642e UIApplicationMain + 1160
    21  Untitled                            0x00002100 main + 102
    22  Untitled                            0x00002091 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

---

I know that `setObject:forKey:` should used with a mutable dictonary . Is there any problem using KVO with NSUserDefaults? By the way, the platform I use is iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

Your code isn't doing what you think it is doing:

```
NSMutableDictionary *configure = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"configure"];
```

This sets `configure` to be the value of your standard defaults to the value of the key `configure`

```
configure = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

This sets `configure` to a new, empty dictionary, not the one you got from User defaults

```
[configure setValue:[NSMutableDictionary dictionary] forKeyPath:@"select"] ;
```

You now put an empty dictionary as the value for the key `select`

```
[configure setValue:[NSMutableDictionary dictionary] forKeyPath:@"select.around"];
```

You are adding another empty dictionary for this key path

```
[configure setValue: @"All" forKeyPath:@"select.around.name"];
```

And you are setting a string value for this key path

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:configure forKey:@"configure"];
```

You are now putting this odd dictionary into NSUserDefaults

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

NSString *keyPath = @"configure.select.around";

NSMutableDictionary *aroundConfigure = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKeyPath:keyPath] mutableCopy];
```

This is just an empty mutable dictionary

```
[aroundConfigure setObject:@"" forKey:@"name"];
```

You are setting an empty string for some key in this dictionary

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:aroundConfigure forKeyPath:keyPath];
```

And then you set this odd dictionary into the the user defaults.

Which is all very confusing.

What is it that you are trying to do?

**Edited to add**

There's no point providing code if you've "simplified" it we can't see what it's supposed to do.

Your app is crashing because you are trying to change a key value pair of a NSDictionary which is immutable instead of a NSMutableDictionary. See line 6 of your trace.

Since you've provided "simplified" code - I don't know where you are doing this.

Comment: hi, abizern, i was going to create a dictionary {"configure":{"select":{"around":{"name":"All" }}}} at the init of app, then to set the keypath configure.selelct.around.name to null string. i has simplied the code. so it seen to make no sence. all i want to know is that why it crash. thanks.

Comment: one up, i think u deserved it.  all i needed was "Your app is crashing because you are trying to change a key value pair of a NSDictionary which is immutable instead of a NSMutableDictionary"  ddddduuuuhhhhh

Answer (score 0):

Today i also faced this problem because i am making data in dictionary like this

```
NSMutableDictionary *Dic =[myMutableAry objectAtIndex:0];
```

after getting data when i am updating my dic value then getting crash

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary
>   setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

Then i did got solution after a lot of research , so just do one thing

```
NSMutableDictionary *Dic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[myMutableAry objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have used the NSUserDefaults is wrong, NSUserDefaults return a non mutable dictionary. That is the cause of this issue. Therefore, you have to request a mutable object explicitly from NSUserDefaults. Please use the code line below.

```
NSMutableDictionary *configure = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"configure"]mutableCopy];
```

This work with me. 
Thanks Good luck :)